# tdlib get notifications settings for (another) user

Tags: telegram, tdlib

I'm using [tdlib](https://github.com/tdlib/td) and currently trying to create another user's profile screen like this one: [image: telegram user profile screen] 
There is usually a field on this screen called "Notifications" containing information on whether or not notifications for given user are muted and if so then for how long. All other fields seem easy to retrieve, but this one is a head-scratcher for me.

All other field are stored in `User` entity, but what am I supposed to do with this one? Call [createPrivateChat](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/docs/classtd_1_1td__api_1_1create_private_chat.html) only to get one field (namely [notificationSettings](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/docs/classtd_1_1td__api_1_1chat.html#a8b1b7428af5babc8785442061b15ba06))? This seems like overkill to me. Isn't there easiest ways to get this? In [this issue](https://github.com/tdlib/td/issues/137) `sapelkinAV` states that "chatID is equals UserId". Is it correct? Even if so it might just be an internal thing that we shouldn't rely on, and I can't find neither proofs nor restrictions on abusing this "feature".

If it is fine, than I could use [getNotificationSettings](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/docs/classtd_1_1td__api_1_1get_notification_settings.html) and pass [notificationSettingsScopeChat](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/docs/classtd_1_1td__api_1_1notification_settings_scope_chat.html) as [scope](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/docs/classtd_1_1td__api_1_1get_notification_settings.html#a281a54e1e486a19e1abf21144a8abc0e) parameter. Would it be the right solution? Any thoughts and advices are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Official answer (obtained from TDLib bot):

> Your usage of createPrivateChat is absolutely correct. To get correct NotificationSettings you need to get information about the corresponding chat.

So I ended up doing exactly that.

> Call createPrivateChat only to get one field (namely notificationSettings)?